# swiperight function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swipe

I am new to jquery. I follow this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_swiperight.asp) to learn the swipe right function. I tried to apply swipe right function in my project. However, it does not have any response when I swipe right. I want the swipe right function triggered when I swipe right at any location of this page. I do not know which part is going wrong. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Tinder-like Marketplace - Mobile Shop Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-touch-fullscreen">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$("body").on("swiperight",function(){
  alert("swipe right");
});
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initSwipe()">

<div id="main">

    <!-- MAIN PAGE -->
    <div id="page">


        <!-- CONTENT CONTAINER -->
        <div class="content-container">

            <!-- Product Header -->
            <div class="content-header">

                <div class="product-title animated fadeIn" id="productName">

                </div><!-- Product title -->

                <img src="images/240x240.png" alt="img" />

                <!-- Product meta -->
                <div class="product-meta animated fadeInUp">
                    <div class="product-title animated fadeIn">$</div>
                    <div class="product-title animated fadeIn" id="productPrice">

                    </div>
                 </div>      
</div>
         <div class="line"></div>


        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT CONTAINER -->


        <div id="swipeLike" class="main-bg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
        <div id="swipeUnlike" class="main-bg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
     </div>

    </div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swipe.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this **100% working**:

Define `swiperight` and `swipeleft` or using this:

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', 'body', function(event){ });
$(document).on('swiperight', 'body', function(event){ });
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).on('swipeleft', 'body', function(event){    
    alert("swipeleft");
    return false;         
});

$(document).on('swiperight', 'body', function(event){     
    alert("swiperight");
    return false;                 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Swiperight Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Try to Swipe Right or Left</p>
</body>
</html>
```